# How to reset the counter to 0 after Ajax Refresh or Submistion to database,

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have this code that sends multiple data in MySQL Database using JQuery Ajax, all works fine but when i try to refresh the page using ajax and add new record, Its populated the number of times equivalent to the last counter.

Below is my **index.php** page;

```
<div id="sample_table_data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="panel border-cyan-dark">
            <div class="panel-heading bg-cyan text-white border-cyan-dark">
                    <div class="panel-title">
                        <h4>PHP - Sending multiple forms data through jQuery Ajax</h4>
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div style="padding-bottom: 10px;" align="right">
                        <button name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>Add Measures
                        </button>
                </div>
                <form method="POST" id="user_form">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="table-responsive margin-bottom-20" >
                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" id="user_data">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>First Name</th>
                                        <th>Last Name</th>
                                        <th>Details</th>
                                        <th>Remove</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Insert">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Form Dialogue Box -->
<div id="user_dialog">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Enter First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control input-sm">
                <span id="error_first_name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Enter Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="form-control input-sm">
                <span id="error_last_name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" name="row_id" id="hidden_row_id">
                <button type="button" name="save" id="save" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Alert Box -->
<div id="action_alert" title="Action"></div>

<script>  
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
     
        var count = 0;

     $('#user_dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen:false,
        width:800
    });


     $('#add').click(function(){
        $('#user_dialog').dialog('option', 'title', 'Add Data');
        $('#first_name').val('');
        $('#last_name').val('');
        $('#error_first_name').text('');
        $('#error_last_name').text('');
        $('#first_name').css('border-color', '');
        $('#last_name').css('border-color', '');
        $('#save').text('Save');
        $('#user_dialog').dialog('open');
    });

    $('#save').click(function(){

        var error_first_name = '';
        var error_last_name = '';
        var first_name = '';
        var last_name = '';
        if($('#first_name').val() == '') {
             error_first_name = 'First Name is required';
             $('#error_first_name').text(error_first_name);
             $('#first_name').css('border-color', '#cc0000');
             first_name = '';
        } else {
             error_first_name = '';
             $('#error_first_name').text(error_first_name);
             $('#first_name').css('border-color', '');
             first_name = $('#first_name').val();
        } 
        if($('#last_name').val() == '') {
             error_last_name = 'Last Name is required';
             $('#error_last_name').text(error_last_name);
             $('#last_name').css('border-color', '#cc0000');
             last_name = '';
        } else  {
             error_last_name = '';
             $('#error_last_name').text(error_last_name);
             $('#last_name').css('border-color', '');
             last_name = $('#last_name').val();
        }


        if(error_first_name != '' || error_last_name != '') {
             return false;
        
        } else {
             if($('#save').text() == 'Save')
             {
                count++;
                output = '<tr id="row_'+count+'">';
                output += '<td>'+first_name+' <input type="hidden" name="hidden_first_name[]" id="first_name'+count+'" class="first_name" value="'+first_name+'" /></td>';
                output += '<td>'+last_name+' <input type="hidden" name="hidden_last_name[]" id="last_name'+count+'" value="'+last_name+'" /></td>';
                output += '<td><button type="button" name="view_details" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs view_details" id="'+count+'">View</button></td>';
                output += '<td><button type="button" name="remove_details" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove_details" id="'+count+'">Remove</button></td>';
                output += '</tr>';
                $('#user_data').append(output);
            }
            else
            {
                var row_id = $('#hidden_row_id').val();
                output = '<td>'+first_name+' <input type="hidden" name="hidden_first_name[]" id="first_name'+row_id+'" class="first_name" value="'+first_name+'" /></td>';
                output += '<td>'+last_name+' <input type="hidden" name="hidden_last_name[]" id="last_name'+row_id+'" value="'+last_name+'" /></td>';
                output += '<td><button type="button" name="view_details" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs view_details" id="'+row_id+'">View</button></td>';
                output += '<td><button type="button" name="remove_details" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove_details" id="'+row_id+'">Remove</button></td>';
                $('#row_'+row_id+'').html(output);
            }
     
          $('#user_dialog').dialog('close');   
       }
});

    
    $(document).on('click', '.view_details', function(){
        var row_id = $(this).attr("id");
        var first_name = $('#first_name'+row_id+'').val();
        var last_name = $('#last_name'+row_id+'').val();
        $('#first_name').val(first_name);
        $('#last_name').val(last_name);
        $('#save').text('Edit');
        $('#hidden_row_id').val(row_id);
        $('#user_dialog').dialog('option', 'title', 'Edit Data');
        $('#user_dialog').dialog('open');
    });


    $(document).on('click', '.remove_details', function(){
        var row_id = $(this).attr("id");
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this row data?")) {
         $('#row_'+row_id+'').remove();
         }  else  {
             return false;
         }
    });
    
    $('#action_alert').dialog({
        autoOpen:false
    });

    
    $('#user_form').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var count_data = 0;
        $('.first_name').each(function(){
         count_data = count_data + 1;
     });
        if(count_data > 0)
        {
         var form_data = $(this).serialize();
         $.ajax({
            url:"pages/insert.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:form_data,
            success:function(data)
            {
             $('#user_data').find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
            count =0;
             $('#action_alert').html('<p>Data Inserted Successfully</p>');
             $('#action_alert').dialog('open');
            }
        })
     }
     else
     {
         $('#action_alert').html('<p>Please Add atleast one data</p>');
         $('#action_alert').dialog('open');
     }
    });
    


 });
</script>
```

and this is my **insert.php** code

```
<?php

//insert.php

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", "root", "****");

$query = "
INSERT INTO tbl_sample 
(first_name, last_name) 
VALUES (:first_name, :last_name)
";

for($count = 0; $count<count($_POST['hidden_first_name']); $count++)
{
 $data = array(
  ':first_name' => $_POST['hidden_first_name'][$count],
  ':last_name' => $_POST['hidden_last_name'][$count]
 );
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute($data);
}

?>
```

Kindly help me how I can reset the counter to 0 after Ajax refresh. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please tell me what you mean by Ajax Refresh?

Comment: @SubhashisPandey I have this button [<button data-container="#main" data-action="reload" hidden="true" id="reload" name="reload"></button>] which has this javacript code [document.getElementById('reload').click();] This is being to reload some part of the page without necessary reloading the whole page. So after reloading using that button, the counter is not reset. Its only reset when a reload the whole page which I'm avoiding since all other components load well with that option,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the var count ouside the $(document)

```
 var count = 0;
 $(document).ready(function(){
```

and in your submit function

```
$('#user_form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var count_data = 0;
    $('.first_name').each(function(){
     count_data = count_data + 1;
 });
    if(count_data > 0)
    {
     var form_data = $(this).serialize();
     $.ajax({
        url:"pages/insert.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:form_data,
        success:function(data)
        {
         $('#user_data').find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
         $('#action_alert').html('<p>Data Inserted Successfully</p>');
         $('#action_alert').dialog('open');
        }
        count =0;
    })
 }
 else
 {
     $('#action_alert').html('<p>Please Add atleast one data</p>');
     $('#action_alert').dialog('open');
 }
});
```

and in additional, you should be using .prop instead of .attr

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but i don't seem to see any change when I place the var count = 0; outside

Comment: please check the update. is your success:function working? because your insert.php did not return anything.